# Highcharts - Combine columns

Tags: highcharts

I try to combine 5 series into 2 columns.
Series 1 should be the "main" column for 1_1 and 1_2. This looks good.

The second column should contain the series 2 and 2_1.
Sadly the two columns overlaped. It should be displayed optical two indentical columns

Can anybody help me please.

Best Regards Andi

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/HszR8/1/`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `grouping: true` for the other series as well. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8vCEs/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But the 2. red/green column(s) should be included in the first blue column. So, 1_1 and 1_2 should be part of column 1.

Comment: Then in Series 1 make `stacking` be true.

Comment: sorry, im to stupid - the result should look like this --> [click me](http://freelog.at/Daten/test.JPG)